# Can't boot Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: boot, 22.04

I installed  Ubuntu 22.04.3 on a new SSD (Windows 11 is running on a separate drive).
The grub boot loader runs correctly but I can't boot Ubuntu normally. I get stuck on the following page:

```
[ 1.19xxxx] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)   
[ 1.19xxxx] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)  
[ 1.19xxxx] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)  
[ 1.19xxxx] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)  
[ 1.19xxxx] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)  
[ 1.19xxxx] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)  
/dev/sdb2: clean xxxxxx/xxxxxxxx files, xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx blocks
```

What details or information are needed to help resolve this issue?

Other posts on this forum suggest that these messages are warnings and not errors. So, I'm finding it hard to diagnose why Ubuntu won't boot.
Any ideas?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149431/discussion-on-question-by-linuxn00b-cant-boot-ubuntu-22-04-3); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Recap of above:

The amdgpu driver is opensource. The binaries for the amdpgu module are provided by package 'linux-firmware'. They sometimes do not load on there own depending on hardware combinations.

The first thing to check is if the binaries are present by doing

```
ls /lib/firmware/amdgpu/*
```

Then check to see if the amdgpu driver is loaded:

```
lsmod | grep 'amdgpu'
```

If it is not, then there are kernel boot parameter that we can give it to help it with that.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Go down to the GRUB_CMD_LINUX= line and add these parameters:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="amdgpu.si_support=1 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.dc=0"
```

Save and exit the file, then do this to pick up the changes

```
sudo update-grub
```

For the Wifi, find the device from

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

The device found for his was:

```
device ID 0b05:17d2 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB-AC56 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8812AU]
```

The driver recommended for RTL8812AU is at: https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au